# O que é Python Egg?

Tags: python

Lendo um livro sobre Python, o autor mostra um comando no qual é possível criar um *Egg* e fazer *upload* do seu pacote no [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) (repositório oficial de pacotes python). Basicamente usando o comando abaixo:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg upload --identity="Jon Snow" --sign --quiet
```

Na verdade não entendi exatamente o que seria esse "Ovo". Seria apenas um módulo? O que é Python Egg? Como de fato pode ser usado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O arquivo `.egg` é um formato de distribuição para pacotes Python. É apenas uma alternativa para uma distribuição de código-fonte ou exe do Windows. Mas note que para o Python puro, o arquivo .egg é completamente multiplataforma.

O próprio arquivo .egg é essencialmente um arquivo .zip. Se você alterar a extensão para "zip", você pode ver que ele terá pastas dentro do arquivo.

Leia sobre aqui: http://mrtopf.de/en/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/

Você pode aprender a como criar o seu aqui: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/python-101-easy_install-or-how-to-create-eggs/

Comment: É básicamente equivalente ao `.jar` do java?

Comment: @BrunoCosta, sim, basicamente isto.